# java SimpleDateFormat CST different date but same result

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Date data1 = new Date(25682400000L);
            Date data2 = new Date(25686000000L);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH-mm-ss");
            TimeZone cdtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
            sdf.setTimeZone(cdtTime);
            String s1 = sdf.format(data1);
            String s2 = sdf.format(data2);
            System.out.println(s1);
            System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

After run the above code,the result:

```
1970-10-25:01-00-00
1970-10-25:01-00-00
```

someone can tell my why?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Uppercase `L`

Using an uppercase `L` at the end of your long integer literals makes the number easier to read. A lowercase `l` tends to look like a one `1` in many fonts.

Write `25682400000L` rather than `25682400000l`.

## 1 Hour Difference

25686000000L - 25682400000L = 3600000L

3600000 milliseconds = 3600 seconds = 60 minutes = 1 hour

If they are exactly an hour apart, why did you see 1 AM for both? Read on.

## Daylight Savings Time

If by "CST", you mean central part of United States, then the craziness of [Daylight Savings Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST) pulls a trick on you. October 25 of 1970 at 2 AM is when [DST ended in that part of the United States](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/1970b.html). So at the stroke of 2 AM, clocks rolled back to 1 AM. So there are two "1 AM" times happening that morning.

See the code example below, and notice two lines both say 1 AM but their time zone offsets (at end) differ (-5 vs -6).

## 3-Letter Codes

Avoid three-letter time zone codes. Problems include:

- They are neither standard nor unique. Multiple different time zones can share the same code.
- They are confusing, as people mix them up with their Daylight Saving Time equivalent.

Either use:

- A [proper time zone name](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).
  For example, `America/Chicago` or `America/Regina`.
- An [time zone offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) from UTC/GMT.
  For example, `-06:00` or `-05:00`.

## Joda-Time

The java.util.Date, .Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

This kind of date-time work is *so* much easier using either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- The new java.time.* classes (in Java 8)

```java
long data1 = 25682400000L;
long data2 = 25686000000L;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Chicago" );

DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime( data1, timeZone );
DateTime dateTime1_UTC_GMT = dateTime1.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime( data2, timeZone );
DateTime dateTime2_UTC_GMT = dateTime2.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime1: " + dateTime1 );
System.out.println( "dateTime1_UTC_GMT: " + dateTime1_UTC_GMT );

System.out.println( "dateTime2: " + dateTime2 );
System.out.println( "dateTime2_UTC_GMT: " + dateTime2_UTC_GMT );
```

When run…

```
dateTime1: 1970-10-25T01:00:00.000-05:00
dateTime1_UTC_GMT: 1970-10-25T06:00:00.000Z

dateTime2: 1970-10-25T01:00:00.000-06:00
dateTime2_UTC_GMT: 1970-10-25T07:00:00.000Z
```